# How would I solve this question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently in year 10 and revising for a mock higher paper, which will take place tomorrow. I'm stuck, how would I go about answering this question?

[image]

Comment: This is tagged as Diophantine equations, is there some restriction not in the original question?

Comment: I didn't really know what this topic was called, any idea?

Comment: I believe the correct tag should be algebra-precalculus

Comment: "probability question"? O.o

Comment: Sorry, fixed both the tag and the question.

Answer (score 2):

Two hints which might help:

- $\dfrac{a}{b} \div \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{a}{b} \times \dfrac{d}{c}$
- $y^2-1 = (y-1)(y+1)$

You might also consider whether or not $3x-1$ is a factor of $3x^2+2x-1$

Comment: Actually, because $$\frac{9x^2 - 1}{3x^2 + 2x - 1} \div \frac{3x + 1}{x - 2} = \frac{9x^2 - 1}{3x^2 + 2x - 1} \cdot \frac{x - 2}{3x + 1}$$ we would have to consider whether $3x+1$ is a factor of $9x^2-1$ (Spoiler alert: it is).

Comment: @2012ssohn: He probably meant $3x - 1$.

Comment: @user2345215: your supposition is correct.